# What are some good resources to learn Statistical Genetics?

Tags: r, machine-learning, references, genetics, high-dimensional

I have a B.S. and M.S. degree in Statistics. I have experience in R. I know the basic structures of Python [Expertise Level: Beginner]. I would really appreciate if you can share with me some resources (preferably, MOOCS and videos).

Comment: If you limit yourself to statistical techniques that actually work, i.e., that provide reproducible answers that are clinically relevant, you'll  have much less to study :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would personally recommend the QTL book:

[A Guide to QTL Mapping with R/qtl](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387921249)

QTL is a process in which we map SNPs to quantitative trait in your phenotype. The point is to understand the correlation between your phenotype and genes causing it. However, it's much more than just calculating Perason's correlation.

You'll learn about backcross, F1 generation, recombination rate, interval mapping, all of which are highly mathematical demanded.

The author of the book is also the author of the `qtl` R package, and he shows many useful examples in the book.

This is one of the best books in biostatistics. Highly recommended.

Comment: Another useful book for introductory genomics could be http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-14475-7. It focus on R and has different examples